# How can I get rid of CORs errors completely in my .Net Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I have a web api on a IIS server using .Net Core 3.1.

It is using the IP and Port of: http://68.181.207.10:8473

I also have 3 web applications that run on the same IIS server. 2 of the apps are .Net 4.7 apps and 1 is a .Net Core app.

The 3 web apps all use the web api.

The 3 apps are:

https://meta.astro.usc.edu (port 443)

http://old.astro.perl.edu (port 80)

http://68.181.207.10 (port 80)

I have set up the API to use CORs, and for the most part, everything is ok and they connect to the API without any issues.

But there are times when I will still run into CORs errors even though I have added all the needed URLs.

In the top of my ConfigureServices method, I am adding the needed URLs that will need access, like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://68.181.207.10:8473", "https://meta.astro.usc.edu", "http://old.astro.perl.edu", "http://68.181.207.10")
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });
    
    
}
```

Then in my Configure method, I am adding `app.UseCors` as you can see below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Is this the proper way of allowing these other web apps to connect to my web api?

The CORs errors seem random and the origins are always one of my 3 web apps.  One doesn't seem to cause more errors than an another.

How can I prevent the intermittent CORs errors that I still receive?

Thanks!

Comment: You write `The CORs errors seem random and the origins are always one of my 3 web apps. One doesn't seem to cause more errors than an another.`. But you specify 4 sites in `WithOrigins`. I suspect there are http/https issues here. I also see that `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` comes before `app.UseCors` in doc, maybe have a look into that too.

Comment: @RoarS. I added `http://68.181.207.10:8473`, which is the URL for the web api itself.  I added that out of desperation...it didn't really seem to help anything though.

Comment: In this case, access logging is your friend. Look especially for failing OPTIONS-requests.

Comment: @RoarS. Thanks, what is a failing OPTIONS requests?  Would I look in my IIS logs?

Comment: OPTIONS request are preflight requests. Please look for requests that are not returning 2XX.

Comment: @RoarS. I see a few 404 returns because the client didn't send the right data.  I also see a few conflict 409 errors because the client was trying to add something that already exists.  How would those cause CORs errors though?  Thanks

Comment: Those requests came through and should be considered as app errors. Hence, there is chance that you don't have any CORS-errors  at all.

Comment: You also need to install IIS CORS module to be installed and configured, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference to properly handle the edge cases when IIS handles CORS requests, not your ASP.NET Core web app.

Comment: If this is a CORS problem, you can install the IIS CORS module in IIS to solve it. If the IIS CORS module is installed in IIS, it still can’t solve it. I think it may have nothing to do with CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Check for Internal Server Errors (500) in problematic requests

Answer (score 1):

After some discussion with OP, this issue might not relate to CORS at all after OP discovered 4XX-errors in the logs.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that why would a 4XX error cause a CORs error to display in the browser console?  THanks

Comment: If you are sure there are CORS-errors, you will still have to check the logs. May I ask what your source is for the CORS errors?

Comment: I've def. had other errors "cause CORS in the browser"... literally just now left an appsettings.json with invalid json (typo) and result was CORS in browser for the UI requesting from the API that was misconfigured. Dunno why.. but..